# How to loop through a ul recursively and find out how many ul's it has in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion, frontend

I'm trying to write a function in jquery that will loop through a ul with nested ul's inside of it. I'd like it to keep track of how many ul's or "layers" in I am, and give a class label to the li children of a ul that correspond to the "layer" that their parent ul is on.
The structure of the html is such`

```html
<div class="region region--megamenu">
  <div class="block block--services-menu">
    <ul class="menu"> 
      <li class="first last expanded active-trail">  
        <a href="/services" class="active-trail">Services</a>
        <ul class="menu"> <!-- This ul can have any number of metacategory li's inside of it -->
          <li class="second layer of li">
            <a href="/metacategory-page">Metacategory Pages</a>
            <ul class="menu"> <!-- This ul can have any number of ul's inside of it -->
              <li>
                <a href="/service-page-url"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/service-page-url"></a>
              </li>
            </ul> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/metacategory-page">Metacategory Pages</a>
            <ul class="menu"> <!-- This ul can have any number of ul's inside of it -->
              <li>
                <a href="/service-page-url"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/service-page-url"></a>
              </li>
            </ul> 
          </li>      
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each li would get a number as a new class label.

So the first li element would get a label `<li class="1 first layer of li">`, and the second layer of li would be labeled `<li class="2 second layer of li">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain JS you can use a recursive function (though a linear one will be faster). This goes down the DOM and adds a class to each LI. When called recursively on an LI, it increments the layer count for that call.

Not sure it fits your purpose, but might be close enough. You could also get the ULs, then add a layer-specific class to their immediate LI children.

The function below could be optimised to skip non–empty elements that won't have LI children (e.g. script elements) if required.

```
<style type="text/css">

.foo-0 {
 background-color: red;
}
.foo-1 {
 background-color: blue;
}
.foo-2 {
 background-color: green;
}

</style>

<div id="d0">
  <ul>
    <li>layer 1
    <li>layer 1
      <ul>
        <li>layer 2
        <li>layer 2
          <ul>
            <li>layer 3
            <li>layer 3
          </ul>
        <li>layer 2
      </ul>
    <li>layer 1
    <li>layer 1
  </ul>
</div>

<script>

/*
** @param {DOM element} root - element to start from, default is document.body
** @param {string} classPre  - prefix for class to add
** @param {number} layer     - current level, default is 0
*/
function addULLayerClass(root, classPre, layer) {
  root = root || document.body;
  layer = layer || 0;

  var node, nodes = root.childNodes;
  var tagName;

  for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    node = nodes[i];
    tagName = node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase();

    // If this is an LI, add class with layer number
    // and call recursively
    if (tagName == 'li') {
      node.className = classPre + '-' + layer;
      addULLayerClass(node, classPre, layer + 1);

    // Otherwise, if it's an element that can have children,
    // call recursively          
    } else if (node.nodeType == 1) {
      addULLayerClass(node, classPre, layer);
    }
  }
}

addULLayerClass(document.getElementById('d0'), 'foo');

</script>
```

Comment: Awesome solution. Doing it the hard way in javascript. Haven't tested it yet, but it looks good at a glance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily accomplish this with the **JQuery** `.find()` method.

**HTML**

```
<div class="region region--megamenu">
  <div class="block block--services-menu">
    <ul class="menu"> 
      <li class="first last expanded active-trail">  
        <a href="/services" class="active-trail">Services</a>
        <ul class="menu"> <!-- This ul can have any number of metacategory li's inside of it -->
          <li class="second layer of li">
            <a href="/metacategory-page">Metacategory Pages</a>
            <ul class="menu"> <!-- This ul can have any number of ul's inside of it -->
              <li>
                <a href="/service-page-url"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/service-page-url"></a>
              </li>
            </ul> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/metacategory-page">Metacategory Pages</a>
            <ul class="menu"> <!-- This ul can have any number of ul's inside of it -->
              <li>
                <a href="/service-page-url"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/service-page-url"></a>
              </li>
            </ul> 
          </li>      
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="info"></div>
```

**JS/JQUERY**

```
var allListElements = $( "ul" );
var ulsInUl = $( "ul.menu" ).find( allListElements ).length;
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Uls in UL Class main: " + ulsInUl;
```

Check out this **JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/aaaprbst/1/

Comment: I don't see where this is adding a class to the LIs based on the UL layer depth.

Comment: Great catch Rob. Even so...thanks henry for the .find() tip! I had previously misunderstood and thought that it only went 1 layer deep.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that I implemented which does exactly what I wanted. Thanks everyone for your contributions.

```
  var parentUL = $( "ul.menu" );
  var startSearchForParentsHere = ".block--services-menu";
      $( startSearchForParentsHere ).find( parentUL ).each(function(){
          layersDeep = $(this).parentsUntil(startSearchForParentsHere, parentUL).length;
          $(this).children().addClass('accordion-layer' + ' ' + layersDeep);
      })
```

Further feedback and other creative solutions are also greatly appreciated!